# Problem in System.assertEquals method

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am writing test class in which I'm inserting 5 custom objects.
My question is that do i need to add System.asertEquals for each and every object or to add to any one is sufficient.

Comment: The term "object" typically refers to the entity, whereas "record" would correspond to the actual row of data. Do you mean to ask if you should assert once per row you have entered? Or are you adding data to 5 different objects and wondering if you should assert for each object. Sorry to be pedantic, but I think this would help clarity for those reading this question.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for adding data to 5 different objects and wondering if i should assert for each object.

Answer (score 3):

Reading your question I'm not sure if you fully understand the concept of apex tests and asserting. I can be wrong, but I'd advise you to really read some documentation and articles to be sure to know what you should be doing.

Examples are:

- [An Introduction to Apex Code Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods)
- [webinar on test best practises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9amswhOxJw)
- [Testing in Apex (open the navigation for more info)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_intro.htm)

While salesforce verifies code coverage, it's better to write tests in the perspective of your functionality. So, **do not write tests to cover your code, but write tests to TEST if your code works the way you want it to work.** As a result, you should have full code coverage, and a lot of code will even be covered multiple times.

To test that your logic is doing what you expect, you have to verify that. The System.Assert methods are there to do this verification. So, typically you are no asserting anything per object or record, but throughout your logical execution flow and the results of it.

I'm aware this is a very high level answer, writing good tests takes time and effort, both in writing and learning how to do so. I'd recommend you try to do more research so that you're sure what you should be trying to do, and than try it. If you get stuck on doing the code, you can make questions and share your code. But it's truly important that you first know and understand what the goal of testing is, and what result you're trying to work towards.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to give a straight Yes or No answer without looking into the complete code.

but my suggestion would be to add separate system.assert for each of the insert you are doing and compare the inserted records or the dependent records / fields that might be created/updated with the expected values.

if possible, you should break your test method into multiple methods one per custom object since each insert might cover multiple triggers and any other associated classes

you can read thru this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests) to get some understanding on the Unit Test Best Practices